Display_name and photo not changing while creating an account via email and password in firebase
I created a sign in function but the display name and the profile doesn't change
this is based on react-native.
export function createUser(auth, Name, Email, Password) {
    if (Name !== "") {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, Email, Password)
            .then((authUser) => {
                alert(`Congratulations ${Name}! You are now Whisprer!`);
                const user = auth.currentUser;

                updateProfile(user, {
                    displayName : Name,
                    photoURL : "../assets/user-default.png"
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
                    alert("That email address is already in use!");
                } else if (error.code === "auth/invalid-email") {
                    alert("That email address is invalid!");
                } else if (error.code === "auth/weak-password") {
                    alert(
                        "Weak Password. Password should be at least 6 charcters"
                    );
                } else if (error.code === "auth/missing-password") {
                    alert("Enter a valid password to continue.");
                } else {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
    } else {
        alert("Enter your valid display name to continue.");
    }
}

can you please help me,
thanks in advance

You're ignoring the result of updateProfile. I assume it also returns a promise. Maybe it's failing - you'd never know without checking the promise.

Also I don't think photoUrl accepts paths to local files.  Shouldn't it be a URL, given the name of the property?

and yes I will change photourl.

@DougStevenson I am so stupid, I found out what was wrong, I imported updateProfile from @react-native-firebase/auth but i configured everything for firebase-auth
